# celery.beat implementation of crontab

Tags: celery

My task is to add a new stream in Wowza media server which must take place at a user specified time. Currently I'm using crontab together with http provider for this purpose. I want a `celery.beat` implementation for this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a one-off task to be executed at a specific time then you don't need to use Periodic Tasks (celerybeat).

Rather you can use the eta/countdown argument to `task.apply_async`:

```
task.apply_async(eta=datetime(2012, 07, 1, 14, 30))


task.apply_async(countdown=30) #   in 30 seconds
```

Read more here:

http://celery.github.com/celery/userguide/calling.html